# Why is Urlopen slow on some websites

Tags: python, urllib, urlopen

I am trying to read a simple text from a Website.
It is working but the speed is the problem.

Any request to that website takes about 20 seconds to get a response. Other websites are fast. With the Browser or the "same" request in Matlab that specific Website is responding immediately:

```
>>from urllib.request import urlopen
>>url = "http://live.glidernet.org/lxml.php?a=0&b=50.5&c=49.5&d=15.2&e=10&z=2" 
>>urlopen (url)
```

Why is `urlopen` slow on some websites?

Comment: Maybe the site has some kind of DDoS prevention that slows automated access to the site. Try setting a user agent maybe.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the website you are trying to access is hosted on a cheap/slow web hosting service. There is nothing you can do about this. It'll be the same even if you access it in the browser.

Some websites set up mechanisms against automated requests to protect against DDoS attacks so their access becomes slow (As suggested by Jammy Dodger).

If it's still slow and you need to access websites in batches, look into Async IO/ Multiprocessing/Queues to create tasks for each website and then open them in parallel.